# Meaning of "sealed covers"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Supreme Court’s interim order asking political parties to disclose, to the Election Commission ***in sealed covers***, details of the donations they have received through anonymous electoral bonds is an inadequate and belated response to the serious concerns raised about the opaque scheme.

What does **sealed cover** mean in this context?

I looked up its meaning but didn't find any thing.

Answer (score 2):

In the context, it refers that the documents must be provided in **covers** (e.g. envelopes) which are closed in such way that the content cannot be open and seen, and the text cannot be read (**sealed**) - not without breaking the seal in a visible way.

The purpose is to keep the contents as secret as possible, or to keep them protected from alteration - information removed, added or changed.

---

Similar with a **sealed enclosure**, which cannot exchange content with the outside.